# Convert a generic IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, code-reuse

In the following code, I need to explicitly mention `CountryId` and `CountryName` but I would like to avoid that and trying to create a `generic method`.

```
public struct KeyValueStruct
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

private static IEnumerable<KeyValueStruct> ConvertPocoToKeyValueList(IEnumerable<CountryPoco> list)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValueStruct>();

    if (list != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            result.Add(new KeyValueStruct()
            {
                Key = item.CountryId,
                Value = item.CountryName
            });
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I know from the list that first property is always integer (which is CountryId in this example) and second property would be String.

I was thinking to implement using `Generics` but am not sure is this the best approach, see my proposed code (it's not working though).

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValueStruct> ConvertPocoToKeyValueList<T>(T list) 
{
    var result = new List<KeyValueStruct>();

    if (list != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            result.Add(new KeyValueStruct()
            {
                Key = item.CountryId,
                Value = item.CountryName
            });
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you have a better idea to achieve the same result, then please propose.

Comment: What is `KeyValueStruct`? Any reason you're not using `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` from the .NET framework? Note that LINQ makes all this trivial, btw... `var result = countries.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(c.CountryId, c.CountryName).ToList();` Sure, you'd need to handle the input being null, perhaps... but you may find that it would be better to prevent that ever happening.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have realized that I missed the KeyValueStruct and just added to the question. I read an article a while ago that having a custom structure is much quicker in terms of performance, so I decided to have my own implementation rather than using .NET's default KeyValuePair. Is there a way to avoid hard-coding the `c.CountryId, c.CountryName`?

Comment: Um, `KeyValuePair` is already a struct... what do you think is faster about your own `KeyValueStruct` type? Admittedly it's a mutable value type, which is a difference... but not a positive one.

Comment: I have decided to use .Net `KeyValuePair`. Thanks @JonSkeet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make that generic by passing the properties to be used as Key and value. I think using the generic `struct` named `KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>` is better than reinventing the wheel yourself:

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>> 
                       ConvertPocoToKeyValueList<TSource, Tkey, TValue>
                                    (IEnumerable<TSource> list,
                                     Func<TSource, Tkey> keySelector,
                                     Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector)
        {
            return list.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>
                                          (keySelector(item), valueSelector(item)));
        }
```

Usage:

```
var result = ConvertPocoToKeyValueList(list, x=> x.CountryId, x=> x.CountryName);
```

You can even do that without using this generic method by using directly:

```
var result = list.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>
                                              (item.CountryId, item.CountryName));
```

Comment: No need to have a `foreach`, just use Linq `Select`, much tidier.

Comment: Also no need for `TKey` and `TValue` types, we already know the structure of `KeyValueStruct`

Comment: @DavidG I truly feel this method is useless as the user can use `Select` to create what he wants without creating a generic method that only calls another generic method.

Comment: If I use the `method` then I avoid defining the `datatype` for KeyValuePair?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute Yes, because generic type inference doesn't work for constructors. So you can't write `new KeyValuePair(item.CountryId, item.CountryName)`

Comment: I think, method is useful and enforces the developer to call it rather than implement their own implementation. Also the `usage` code is much simple, IMHO. Hope my reasoning to stick with method make sense?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute It doesn't harm and it prevent you from repeating the same code multiple times, so it might make sense if you're using it a lot.

Comment: Yes, will be using a lot. As you might have already guessed it will be used to feed the data for drop down boxes. Thanks a lot!